# Login routine for password protected website

Tags: authentication, password-protection

You are writing the login routine for a password protected website. Give examples of specific user input errors that you might want to catch, and how you might deal with them.

This is an interview question

I answered this as follows

We should add both client side errors and server side errors.

Client side error:
Check if user put nothing in username field. We can show message using javascript that “username not entered”
Server side error:
We can check if username does not exist in database and can throw error message.
We can check if password does not match in database for entered username.

Can anyone suggest. Are these the only error we can catch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd consider syntactically invalid usernames (empty; too short or too long; containing invalid characters like possibly spaces, quote marks or shell/SQL metacharacters; structurally invalid, i.e., starting with dot or number), and syntactically invalid passwords (too short or even empty, too "simple", or equal to username). All these cases you can validate client side with JS, recycling the same code for the "Creating new user, choose user and password" view.

Server side, you might have backend connection error (i.e. not being able to tell whether the user does exist -- not exactly an user error, but we might want to manage it here nonetheless), user not found, password mismatch, and possibly "login disabled" (this is quite common on auto-create-user website: the login exists but must be validated by clicking on a link sent through email. Then again, one might want to place these "not-yet-users" in a storage apart to avoid clogging/churning on the real user database). Of course you might also want to add a special disable state and message ("Your membership fee is overdue"). Other additional "errors" and "warnings" may be added here, e.g. "You're not logging from your usual IP block(s) [, would you mind answering this security question?]" or "password expired, choose another password".

Comment: Nice list of server-side issues.  Validating the characters/length etc of username and password should be there too if you're talking about auto-create-user, as you shouldn't assume your client page is the real and only source of requests and request content reaching the server.  Another interesting question is whether to bother with client-side validation of username and password length and content - even for adding accounts it needs to be validated on the server side and doing it redundantly is questionably-spent development time and extra delocalised maintenance.

Comment: Very well taken point. Client side checks should only be used as a convenience to the client (to save a page submit or AJAX call and improving responsivity), never simply be relied upon. A nice, albeit marginal, side effect is saving the server the extra load of checking for good-faith errors, which never leave the client: most requests will be valid, and processing them will be worthwhile. Maintenance costs may be contained by implementing syntax checks through regexes, which (in most languages) may be shared between server and client.

Answer (score 2):

IMO, the main issue (assuming [SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) as the database for the users and password) is [SQL](http://xkcd.com/327) [Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), that for example adds a specific user as an admin access.

Dealing with it can be done using libraries in the server side to handle all user input — rather then trying to do it on your own.

Comment: Hi Amit, are you sure that here main issue is SQL injection. Can you please elaborate it bit more.

Comment: @user1431954: In my opinion - yes. A malicious SQL injection can drop your entire data base, add a user as an admin, remove users and more. Have a look at the wikipedia article I attached on sql injections.